# rake neo4j:install[community-latest] - The `neo4j-rake_tasks` gem is no longer a dependency of the `neo4j-core` gem

Tags: ruby, neo4j, rake

I am following this instruction, "Getting Started with Neo4j and Ruby",  https://neo4j.com/developer/ruby-course/.

**Here is how you would setup your asset portal Rails app:**

```
rails new asset_portal -m http://neo4jrb.io/neo4j/neo4j.rb -O
cd asset_portal
rake neo4j:install[community-latest]
rake neo4j:start
```

But after I run

```
rake neo4j:install[community-latest]
```

I got this note

```
The `neo4j-rake_tasks` gem is no longer a dependency of the `neo4j-core` gem.
If you would like to use the rake tasks, you will need to explicitly include the `neo4j-rake_tasks` gem in your project.
Please note that the `neo4j-rake_tasks` gem is only for development and test environments (NOT for production).
Be sure to require the `neo4j-rake_tasks` gem AFTER the `neo4j-core` and `neo4j` gems.
For more details see the Neo4j.rb documentation
```

What can I do now to make this statement, **rake neo4j:install[community-latest]**, work?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I need to add the following lines to GemFile

```
gem 'neo4j-core'

gem 'neo4j-rake_tasks'
```

And then run the commands

```
bundle install
rake neo4j:install[community-latest]
rake neo4j:start
```

Answer (score 1):

only add the flowing snippet

```
 gem 'neo4j-rake_tasks'
```

bundle install

Hopefully would solve your problem.